# unable to load the date into mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load a csv file which has date format as 930101 into mysql, it shows as null in my table in mysql, I have used SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@date,'%y-%m-%d'), it dosen't seem to help , would appreciate any help

Comment: 930101 is this date?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need

```
SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@date,'%y%m%d')
```